# How can I make my MsgBox Appear if the Equip_No is not equal to the value in the Equip_no Textbox?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am using a visual studio 2010 and Microsoft Sql server 2005.
I want to make the MsgBox("Unable to delete. Equipment Number is not found!", vbInformation, "Error") appear whenever a user enters an incorrect Equip_No.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Delete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click

    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
        MsgBox("Operation cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'If Command.CommandText = "SELECT FROM dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl WHERE Equip_No = @Equip_No" Then
    Try
        Dim Command As New SqlCommand
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=HPC-107;Database=MRPdb;integrated security= ...")
        con.Open()
        Command.Connection = con
        Command.CommandText = " DELETE FROM dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl WHERE Equip_No = '" & Equip_No.Text & "'"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = Command
        da.DeleteCommand = Command
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        msgdeleted()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    'Else : MsgBox("Unable to delete. Equipment Number is not found!", vbInformation, "Error")

    'End If
    'Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Equip_No", Equip_No.Text)

    Grid()
    ClearTextBoxes()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns an integer that is the number of rows affected by the command.
In your case, if the number is zero, then you could print your message

```
 Dim result = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 if result = 0 then
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to delete. Equipment Number is not found!")
 else
    MessageBox.Show("Record deleted")
 End if
```

Said that, please take note that.

- An SqlDataAdapter is not required in this context.
- You should use a parameterized query and not a string concatenation

  ```
  Dim Command As New SqlCommand
  Dim con As New SqlConnection("Server=HPC-107;Database=MRPdb;integrated security= ...")
  con.Open()
  Command.Connection = con
  Command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.inhouse_hardware_marterfile_tbl " & _
                        "WHERE Equip_No = @eqno"
  Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eqno", Equip_No.Text)
  Dim result = Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  ```

Comment: Okay sir! I still dont have enough reputation

Comment: Don't worry. With some well written questions and some good answers you will reach the cap really fast.